# For loop doesn't stop on the strlen

Tags: c, string, for-loop

My biggest problem is on this line:

> for(i=0;i<=strlen(enc);i++) ->

**7th line of the function decifrar:**
It keeps the loop even with the memset used to clear the memory (it's even bigger than the string length)

**Note** if I use the actual length of the string in that line the code does works (i.e. replacing strlen(enc) with 60 )

```
void decipher(int k, char *enc){
     char alfa[]="9876543210zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcbaZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA9876543210zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcbaZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA";
     char *pch;
     int i;
     for(i=0;i<=strlen(enc);i++){
        pch=strchr(alfa, enc[i]);
        if (pch) enc[i] = *(pch + k),enc[i]=tolower(enc[i]);
     }
     printf("%s",enc);
}
int main(){
    int keys[6]={1,4,15,24,12,20},i;
    char *txt="rfgr r hz grkgb fvzcyrf dhr cergraqr fre grfgnqb ab cebtenzn";
    char *txttemp=malloc(sizeof(char)*1024);

    for(i=0;i<6;i++){
        printf("\n\n\t Attempt number: %d\n\n",i+1);
        memset(txttemp,'\0',sizeof(char)*strlen(txt)+30);
        memcpy(txttemp, txt, strlen(txt));
        decipher(keys[i],txttemp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What is the point that I am missing? Is the usage of strlen wrong?

Comment: You shouldn't use a function like `strlen()` in the for-condition. It is evaluated every time around the loop. The character at `a[strlen(a)]` is a null character. Do you really want to process that?

Comment: And, because it's evaluated every time around the loop, and you're overwriting your terminating `'\0'`, that's why your `for` loop "isn't stopping", because when you remove that `'\0'` your "string length" is likely to suddenly become enormous. Also, as an aside, don't use `sizeof(char)`, since it's always `1`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's `<` not `<=` in the for-loop.

But as a Note: avoid that pattern. Strlen means you count the length of the string, but you probably should already know it from somewhere (i.e. when you receive it: the file length, the number of charecters returned etc...). Save it and take that value as the length. This is the source of a lot of security holes in programs (a [buffer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow)).

`std::string` has this as a built-in functionality and it's what I would recommend over a plain char* almost all of the time (that is if you can use C++)

Comment: At the very least hoist it out of the loop. `int n = strlen(enc); for( i = 0; i < n; i++)...`

Comment: The question is about C; `std::string` doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes, but it's a typical beginner's-error, so I added it and said that it can only be used in C++, because I thinke it's not unlikely, that using C++ is feasible and the author just said C ;D

Comment: It doesn't really matter whether it's "feasible" - you wouldn't answer a Python or an Awk question by suggesting the author use C++, and the same ought to go for a C question.

Comment: I see your point, but when someone sais C they often mean C++. The code is C code, but I thought it might be valuable to the author or futur readers.

Comment: If someone says C and mean C++, the traditional response would be to correct them and re-tag the question. In this particular case, the posted code wouldn't compile as C++.